# Receive Parameter in spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, parameters

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Fin_AddCheckBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
JsonResponse addCoaCategory(
        @RequestParam(value="checkbookNumber", required=true) String checkbookNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="checkbookName", required=true) String checkbookName,
        @RequestParam(value="startNumber", required=true) long startNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="bankId", required=true) long bankId,
        @RequestParam(value="currencyId", required=true) long currencyId,
        @RequestParam(value="noOfLeves", required=true) int noOfLeves,
        @RequestParam(value="alertAt", required=true) int alertAt,
        @RequestParam(value="isActive", required=true) int isActive, Map map, Model model) {
```

I have two table in one form ! I want to receive first table elements by name by specifying @RequestParam(value="startNumber", required=true) long startNumber; 
**but**
second table elements in Map i.e Map map

How to receive some parameter with name and all other element in map ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create your own objects : 

public class MyMap {
    private String myObject1; // dont forget that these names should be same as @RequestParam values

    private Integer myObject2;

    //setters and getters. they are must!!

}

public class MyMap2 {
    private String my1;

    private Integer my2;

    //setters and getters. they are must!!

}
```

Now put this object as a parameter of your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Fin_AddCheckBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addCoaCategory(MyMap myMap, MyMap2 myMap2, BindingResult result) {
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        // work with myMap myMap2
    }
}
```